# Make dynamic path in node and express js

Tags: node.js, express, routes, js-routes

I am trying to make route dynamic like /review-{title}-{id}
, but causing error don't know why, Also if user enter the wrong params than how to handle that.
My client requirement is like above, I am not good in node and express please anyone suggested how to make routes like above.
Also if I needed to make route like this /review/:title/:id format than how can I make like that.

I am trying but it redirect me out to the 404 page,

Please find my existing code details inside,
    server.js

```
this is working.. 
app.get('/review', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/review.html'));
});

but not this one..
app.get('/review-*-*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/review.html'));
});

Also not this one working
app.get('/review/*/*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/review.html'));
});

This is 404 page which call evrytime while accessing dynamic pages
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/404.html'));
});
```

Comment: You may be interested by this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623041/how-to-configure-dynamic-routes-with-express-js

Answer (score 2):

Check out the syntax for routes in [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

In most cases you're better off using route params, e.g.:

```
app.get('/review/:title/:id', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/review.html'));
});
```

Some more flexibility (but more opaque for most developers) would be to match on regex.

I think you can put a * in the middle of words (they give an example like '/abc*def', but I'm not sure how nicely that plays with the other things you're doing, and I don't think you can have multiple *'s in the pattern if you do that.)