# Redirect to generated url with express (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express

Currently, in my app i am hosting a nodejs web server with express. All I want to do is generate a html file with unique name , create a route with this name and redirect server to this route. I have already generated file with unique name but I can't find my way with routes. Is it possible to work this way?

Comment: Hey, I guess this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623041/how-to-configure-dynamic-routes-with-express-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most intuitive solution seems for me the one that would use the [show action in RESTful routing](https://gist.github.com/alexpchin/09939db6f81d654af06b) and which consists in using, for your case, the file names as parameters of the request.

Basically, you'd have something like this:

```
app.get('/files/:uniqueHtmlFileName', function(req , res){ 
    res.sendfile(req.params.uniqueHtmlFileName+".html");
  });
```

More on:

- [Dynamic routing in Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623041/how-to-configure-dynamic-routes-with-express-js)
- [RESTful routing](https://gist.github.com/alexpchin/09939db6f81d654af06b)
- [Rendering HTML view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529586/render-basic-html-view)
- [sendFile() in Express.js](http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#res.sendFile)

**N.B:**
The code I showed will probably not work right of the bat as you'd probably need to take care of path issues, refer to the `sendFile()` doc for a more comprehensive code example.

Comment: This worked. But i am stucked somewhere else. Do you know how can I navigate to this url automatically? Specifically, in a js file I do some calculations inside a function and I want to redirect browser automatically (user doesn't need to do any action) after this function completes.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is a redirect with `res.redirect("destination-url-here")`, feel free to share further details if this does not cut it. Check-out this link: http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html